# Simple CakePHP ActiveRecord save problem: Why does the field save `NULL` instead of the value I assign it?

Tags: php, cakephp, activerecord, null, saving-data

First, I've been using CakePHP for a long time, and I'm very comfortable with the API.  I'm pretty sure this is going to be a **face-palm** error, but I'll need some fresh eyes on this because I've been stuck for over an hour.

I have three models, `User`, `Job`, and `Company`.

1. `Company` hasMany `User`
2. `Company` hasMany `Job`

Sometimes, when a user is updating a job record, the user needs to change the job's `company_id` field.  When this happens, I also have a requirement to change the user's own `company_id` field.  So, in effect, the `User` and the `Job` will both be re-assigned to a different company.

In the CRUD update method of the `JobsController`, I have added this logic:

```
$this->Job->User->read(NULL, $this->Session->read('User.id'));
$this->Job->User->set('company_id', $this->data['Job']['company_id']);
$this->Job->User->save();
```

I have verified using typical debugging techniques, like `var_dump()` that `$this->Session->read('User.id')` contains a proper value, and `$this->data['Job']['company_id']` contains the correct value that was submitted from the form helper.

The correct `User` record is updated, because the `modified` timestamp in the table indicates that it is so, but the `company_id` field is set to `NULL` instead of the correct `company_id` from the data array.

Interestingly, after the above snippet I save the `Job` record, and it *does* get updated with the correct `company_id` (using the same `$this->data` array).

It's just `$this->Job->User->save()` that seems to pass a `NULL` value to the table.

**<facepalm type="lame">**

Turns out a new junior dev monkeyed with the code at a further point in the application flow.  This dev was trying to complete the same ticket, and incorrectly executed a save method loaded with `NULL` data (*after* the job data save, which is why I didn't notice, since I was working *before* the job save...).

At any rate, walking down the SQL dump made me find the error, so credit should be given to @dhofstet for pointing me down the right debug path.  Thank goodness for version control.

**</facepalm>**

Comment: Did you check the generated SQL statement?

Comment: @dhofstet No!  For whatever reason I'm an idiot!  I'll check that now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that $this->data['Job']['company_id'] is not null?
Maybe there is some problem with validation. Have you tried saveField instead set & save?

Comment: "I have verified using typical debugging techniques, like `var_dump()` that [...] `$this->data['Job']['company_id']` contains the correct value that was submitted from the form helper."

Comment: What about the other question? Have you tried saveField instead set & save?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the second question.  Yes, I have tried saving multiple ways.  I have tried setting the model id manually (`$this->Job->User->id = 1`) and using `savefield('company_id', $this->data['Job']['company_id'])`.  I get the same result.

Comment: It's weird.
Have you tried to test it with values of your choice to discard passing params as the problem? e.g.:
$this->Job->User->read(NULL, 1);
$this->Job->User->set('company_id', 18);
$this->Job->User->save();

Comment: I didn't notice it before but I've a doubt. Why are you using "$this->Job->User->read" instead "$this->User->read"? Apparently Job and User models have no relationship between them.

Comment: Yes, I failed to say that User hasMany jobs, sorry to lead you astray.  The above code is in the jobscontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

a simple

```
$this->Job->User->save($this->data);
```

will to the trick

assuming you fill up the array with [User][company_id] etc